# logo and avatar one on the left and one on the right - css blazor

Tags: html, css, blazor

I have this as my top navigation bar in blazor :

```
<div>
    <main>
        <div class="top-row px-4">
            
            <RadzenImage Path="/SSE_Logo_RGB.png" Style="width: 9rem;"></RadzenImage>
            <RadzenIcon Icon="account_circle" IconColor="white"></RadzenIcon>
            
        </div>

        <article class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </article>
    </main>
</div>
```

And I need the image to be on the left and then icon on the right of this div class.
Here is my CSS for the top-row

```
.top-row {
    background-color: #a2b2c8;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d5d5;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    height: 3.5rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

}
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this as its driving me crazy. thanks

Comment: use `grid` instead of `flex` then just make `2 col`, `1fr`

Comment: You can simply set `justify-content: space-between`. Is that what you want to achieve?